# Unable to call .ashx file from repeater control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am facing problem while calling .ashx file from repeater control in .aspx page.
I put break point in .ashx file, but process execution not going to that line.
Where the page is placed in sub folder and at first it is having membership authentication later i changed it to forms authentication.

Comment: can u share code/markup for .aspx page?

Comment: <asp:Repeater id="RPT_EW" runat="server"> <ItemTemplate> <img src="Mile Stones\MyHandler.ashx" /> </ItemTemplate> </asp:Repeater>

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your path to ashx is correct - for example, as it's a relative path, make sure that when considered relative to your page, whether it points to correct location. Use `/` instead of `\`.

You can use tool such as Fiddler or Firebug on Firefox to inspect the requests/responses from/to browser. For example, you can see if the request path to ashx is correct or not and if it's incorrect, you will notice 404 response from server.

Comment: my aspx page is in Mile Stones folder and MyHandler.ashx is also in same folder.So now if i use Src="MyHandler.ashx" it is not calling that ashx file itself.But, same is working in sample application but there i used ASP.NET Empty Web Site, is there any authentication problem for my main application

Comment: @ahobul, use tool such as fiddler! From looking at server response, you will know what is the issue. Or else you can directly type the ashx url in browser address bar and see what's the server response is!